# Makefile and updating files

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm working on a project with a few directories with my makefile one level above all of them.  When I update and of the code/header files and re-make, it says 'Nothing to be done for 'all''.  Is there a way to force make to check all of the directories and therefore realise that some components have to be remade?  Cheers
Jack

Comment: Do your Makefile targets depend on all source and header files they are built from? This is exactly what make is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could forcibly enter the sub-directories each time:

```
SUBDIRS = dir1 dir2

.PHONY: all
all: subdirs final_target

.PHONY: subdirs
subdirs:
    for d in $(SUBDIRS); do $(MAKE) -C $$d; done

.PHONY: final_target
final_target:
    echo "Do something here..."
```

This scheme, to enter all sub-directories, are actually very common.

Comment: Wouldnt that only work if I had a seperate makefile in each subdir?  I only have the one makefile at the moment.  Also out of curiosity what doe the .PHONY command do? I've seen it used for 'clean' commands before.  Cheers!

Comment: @JackMedley Ah yes that's correct. Then you simply need to list all files in all sub-directories as dependencies when needed. The`.PHONY` target tells Make that its dependencies are not real files, so they are always "built" when referenced.